# Zero divisors in a ring $Q^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I was asked to show that the ring $\langle\mathbb{Q^2},\oplus,\otimes _m \rangle$, where $m \in \mathbb{N}$ and $(a,b)\oplus(c,d)=(a+c,b+d)$, and $(a,b)\otimes _m (c,d)= (ad+mbc, ac+ bd)$ contains zero divisors $\Leftrightarrow$ when $m$ equals to the square of a rational number.

As I understood I need to show that $ab = 0$ or $ ba=0,\; $  for some $a\in \mathbb{Q^2}$ ,where $b \in \mathbb{Q^2} \setminus \{0\}$

This is what I have done by far. Concluding $m=-(\frac{a}{b})^2$

[[image: This is what I have done by far. Concluding <span class=]$m=-(\frac{a}{b})^2$." />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mu2RJ.jpg)

1. Should I operate with the modulus? or just with the coordinates according under the operations allowed in this ring?.
2. I want to know what I am supposed to do with the
   $(a,b)\oplus(c,d)=(a+c,b+d)$ information. I got confused with the
   vector $\mathbb{Q^2}$ information and vector:

Comment: That should be $(a,b) \otimes (c,d) = (ac + mbd, ad + bc)$ otherwise the multiplication isn't associative (or commutative, or have an identity).

Comment: Thanks! I understood.@TrevorGunn Could you comment my solution? may be something to add?

Comment: @deEgea Well the entirety of your work is based on an incorrectly given definition, so in any case none of it is "correct".

Comment: @BenGrossmann Understand, could you suggest me how to start or give me some hints. Could you tell me more precesily what is the correct definition?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Your ring is isomorphic to ${\mathbf Q}[x]/(x^2-m)$, which has no zero divisors if and only if $x^2-m$ is irreducible over $\mathbf Q$.